# SwiftUI - Updating Struct/Array Variables

Tags: arrays, variables, swiftui, struct

I want to be able to update a variable in a dataset.
Set out below:

```
 struct WeatherData: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var month: String
    var value: Int
}

@State var monthlyOutput = [
    (chartline:"Daylight", data: [
        WeatherData(month:"Jan", value: 42),
        WeatherData(month:"Feb", value: 53),...
```

If I wanted to be able to alter, say, the "Feb" value I can't workout the construct to do so. Below, for example, doesn't work.

```
[chartline:"Daylight",[WeatherData.month("Feb"), WeatherData.value]] = 1
```

What is throwing me is the chartline name that it is listed only once whereas the rest of the data is listed in full, as a standard fully padded array.

How, can I, change such a variable?

Comment: A value type can be modified by replacing the item in `monthlyOutput` or by index for example `monthlyOutput[0].data[1].value = 1`

Comment: I understand the construct now. Again. many thanks.